# Create a column with data reverse to another column's data in DataTable bound Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, reverse

I need to reverse the data of a datagridview column a put it on another column of the same datagridview.

The datagridview have a Datatable as a source.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= plazo; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dtDetalle.NewRow();
    //#
    row["nrocuota"] = i.ToString();
    //Fecha de vencimiento
    fecha_pago = fecha_pago.AddMonths(1);
    row["vencimiento"] = fecha_pago.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    //Plazo
    FPlazo = Convert.ToDateTime(row["vencimiento"]);
    plazodias = (decimal)(FPlazo - dtpkrfecha.Value).TotalDays;
    row["plazo"] = Convert.ToInt32(plazodias); //This is the column that I need to reverse

    dtDetalle.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `reverse the data of a datagridview column`.  That could cause every row to be changed!

Comment: If column A have the values 1,2,3,4,5. I need create another column with the values 5,4,3,2,1 - @Plutonix

Comment: Just add the intended ciolumn to the DataTable!

Comment: Can you show me how to do it please. I've tried to pass the column values to an array, then use Array.Reverse() but can't put it back into the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
public DataTable ReverseRowsInDataTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
    DataTable outputTable = inputTable.Clone();

    for (int i = inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        outputTable.ImportRow(inputTable.Rows[i]);
    }

    return outputTable;
}
```

So basically you fill new table with your old table but from the last index.

EDIT: I missunderstood your question. For reversing column it is same principle as for whole datatable but instead of row, you will do it with columns in single row.

So just create new DataRow and

```
for int(i = yourDataRow.Cells.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    //and here insert value in your new DataRow column by column but calculate if max i = 5, then when i = 5, new column in newDataRow needs to be 0, 4-1 etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will reverse all the columns of the Datatable. I need reverse only one column and left the others without changes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Omni i edited answer. Also i will write full code tomorrow, now it is 4:05 AM so i need to go sleep.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will wait for your full code. Thanks for your time